# What are the Best Practices for Cache And Syncing in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, core-data

I am looking for a way to cache data on client side, and sync that data with server data on basis of time stamp, i am worried about which way to go whether to use Coredata or Sqlite.

I know CoreData is not RDBMS and it takes in Memory as a complete object space, On the Other Side Sqlite is much powerful,

What is best choice CoreData or Sqlite.

Further in Future version (that is expected) if server data base undergo some changes like any column added to Table or Deleted for some reason or Updated, How i can Plan to achieve Scalability.

Any Thoughts Much Appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: "takes in Memory as a complete object space". Core Data gives you full control of the size of the in-memory object graph.

Answer (score 0):

I've always preffered SQLite but I guess they're both somewhat equivalent to each other. SQLite is just so much more simple (from my experience, which is junior-level) when you need to use it, specifically with stuff like FMDB (git it!).

I've always been told that SQLite > CoreData (if we wanna make it that simple). And I just happen to feel the same way after having used both. Though on the other hand, if you're not using FMDB, SQLite is painful to code with.

Scalability? You'd need to update your app and your tables, that's the same for both choices. Again, i kinda feel this is completly opinion based when I say that sqlite feels easier and more comfortable to play with. Wether its using SQL or updating the DB.

Now I wanna emphasize this before i get any downvoted : it's really how I feel and not a simple fact that everyone agrees on. Wait for some more answers. I've only used CoreData in 2 or 3 different projects, where i've used SQLite in way more, so maybe i'm already too used to one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a proponent of using the highest level API available for the task at hand, so in this case I'd vote for CoreData. Although I must say that it has its perks. Especially when you could run into a situation where you need to sync your data, CoreData might not be ideal.

When talking to an API I had good experiences with the [Mantle Framework](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) developed by GitHub themselves. Mantle itself does not persist data, but I'm pretty sure there is a solution to "connect" it to CoreData. There is even an [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) extension available, [Overcoat](https://github.com/gonzalezreal/Overcoat), that lets you easily create MTLModels. On that subject have a look at [this](http://www.paylas.com/video/mattt-thompson--kod-io-2013) talk by [Mattt Thompson](http://nshipster.com).

Talking about AFNetworking, depending on your use case it might be easier to let AFNetworking cache the HTTP responses and not worry about persisting at all since requests pull the data from the cache first before going to the Network.